# $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M, N)$ and $M^* \otimes_A N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebras

If $U$ and $V$ are vector spaces over some field $k$ and $U$ is finite dimensional with basis $\{u_i\}_i$, then we know that $\def\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}$

$$\Hom_k(U, V) \to U^* \otimes_k V,\quad f \mapsto \sum_i u^* \otimes f(u)$$

is an isomorphism, where $U^* = \Hom_k(U, k)$. Does there exist a similar statement if $A$ is a $k$-algebra and $M$ and $N$ are $A$-modules such that $M$ is finite dimensional over $k$ with basis $\{m_i\}$? The obvious map

$$\Hom_A(M, N) \to M^* \otimes_A N,\quad f \mapsto \sum_i m_i^* \otimes f(m)$$

does not work, because if $A$ is finite dimensional with basis $\{a_i\}$, then

$$\Hom_A(A, N) \to A^* \otimes_A N,\quad f \mapsto \sum_i a_i^* \otimes f(a) = \sum_i a_i^* \otimes a f(1) = \sum_i a_i^* a \otimes f(1) = (\dim_k A) (1^* \otimes f(1)).$$

But even if one adds an additional factor of $(\dim_k A)^{-1}$, it does not seem to work. In particular, this would give an isomorphism

$$A \otimes_A N \cong N \cong \Hom_A(A, N) \cong A^* \otimes_A N,$$

which seems ridiculous. What's the correct way to go?

Comment: Such an isomorphism exists if $M$ is finitely generated projective (over $A$) but not otherwise. The dimension of $M$ over $k$ is not really relevant.

Comment: Is the 'otherwise' part clear? I don't see how to show that.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dual+basis
Quotation: The concept of a dual basis is a way of characterizing projective modules, alternative to their characterization as direct summands of free modules.

Comment: @AndrewHubery I think this is slightly different, because the dual basis in that sense talks about elements in $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M, A)$, and not in $M^* = \operatorname{Hom}_k(M, k)$.

Comment: The ‘similar statement’ for modules over a ring is that when $M$ is a (finitely generated) projective module and one uses the dual basis, which is why Qiaochu Yuan says that the $k$-dimension of $M$ is not relevant.

Comment: Alternatively one can use the tensor Hom adjunction to get $\mathrm{Hom}_A(M,N^\ast)=(M\otimes_AN)^\ast$.